# Sort by the sum of mutual likes/dislikes of all users, separated by like or dislike

Tags: mysql

I want to **sort page likes/dislikes** by all users that I share the **same page likes/dislikes** with and order it by the most likes/dislikes combined.

I tried joining the same table itself but I don't know how to separate the `COUNT` that I get likes and dislikes at the same time without changing the `WHERE`-condition.

Assuming **my uid (user id) is 544** I have this query:

```
SELECT l1.id, l1.uid, l1.item_id, l1.status, l2.id, l2.uid, l2.item_id, l2.status, 
  COUNT(*) AS common_likes,
  COUNT(*) AS common_dislikes // should check for status = 0
FROM pages_likes AS l1
JOIN pages_likes AS l2 ON l1.item_id = l2.item_id
WHERE l1.uid != 544 AND l2.uid = 544
GROUP BY l1.uid
ORDER BY common_likes DESC, l1.uid DESC
LIMIT 10
```

In fact **this query is delivering wrong results** in general since I can check single user-pages for common likes/dislikes and the count is different that the result I'm getting from this query of `common_likes`. For example I have `www.domain.com/user/123/` and see all common likes/dislikes where I'm using `uid IN (123,544)` to check common likes/dislikes of specific user id's. But now I need an overview of all users (`www.domain.com/users/`), so it should be a different query.

So the query I posted is the one I came up with and needs to be improved.

Table structure:

`page_likes`: `id`, `uid`, `item_id`, `status`, `date`

`uid` means user id.

`status = 1`  means like.

`status = 0` means dislike.

Query output:

[image]

Comment: You are getting same count for both likes and dislikes. Is this your problem?

Comment: Yes, because it's the same SELECT I'm using with other aliases. Like I said also the count of likes is incorrect and I want to seperate it in likes and dislikes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SUM` with `case` statement instead of `count` like below

```
SELECT l1.id, l1.uid, l1.item_id, l1.status, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS common_likes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS common_dislikes
FROM pages_likes AS l1
WHERE l1.uid = 544
GROUP BY l1.uid
ORDER BY common_likes DESC, l1.uid DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Also there is no need for `self-join` in your scenario.

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: Thanks, but with your query you only check for user id 544. I want to `SELECT` **ALL users** that I have common likes and dislikes with. This will only output my own likes/dislikes and not the ones I share with others.

Comment: @Vay Can you elaborate your question with sample data and expected result from that data. Please provide sample data as text instead of image.